# ibatis dynamic SQL using for How to implement between two date by IBATIS dynamic Sql

Tags: dynamic-sql, ibatis

I would like to do a A complex dynamic select statement in Ibatis something like this

```
select * from emp 
//when dateParam between 2012-03-1 and 2013-03-01 then
union
select * from emp1
//when dateParam between 2014-03-1 and 2015-03-01 then
union
select * from emp2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something like this:

```
select * from emp  
<isLessEqual  property="dateParam" compareValue="2015-03-01">
  union
  select * from emp1
</isLessEqual>
<isLessEqual  property="dateParam" compareValue="2013-03-01">
  union
  select * from emp1
</isLessEqual>
```